# ubuntu shell script checking for

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, shell-script

I'm looking for something like this:

```
if [ "`python2.7 -V`" == "Python 2.7" ] ;then
    echo "woh"
fi
```

inside the if statement ... check to see if running the command

```
$ python2.7 -V
```

returns the string "Python 2.7"

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: haha yes i tried it .. and it doesnt print "woh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python -V` sends its output to stderr.

```
[ "`python2.7 -V 2>&1`" == "Python 2.7" ]
```

Comment: Works like a charm!